# iPad App that can store longer history than Safari

Tags: ipad, applications, safari

Is there an app that can keep longer than a week or so of browsing hisotry, which is what seems to be available in Safari?
The longer the better...

Answer (score 1):

I have been using iCabMobile for quite a while. It's a good and very configurable browser.

Strangely enough it's history setting is not in number of days but a numerical "size" from 0 thru 10,000. It comes by default at 100. Not sure what it means so you may need to ask the developer.